# Why doesn't getting text from div via function parameters work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Take a look on the fiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zmu4k/3/

```
$(document).on("click", ".right", function() {
    $("#debug").append("<br />Regular on-click: " + $(this).text());
});

$(document).on("click", ".right", {
    qid: $(this).text()
}, GoToQuestion);


$(document).on("click", ".wrong", {
    qid: $(this).text()
}, GoToQuestion);

function GoToQuestion(event) {
    $("#debug").append("<br />Passing data via function - event.data.qid: " + event.data.qid);
}
```

Pressing 1 gets the first attempt right but its second attempt when pressing 1 does NOT because of function data arguements. The other "right" "Wrong" divs fail it, too.

What is going on here?

Comment: Where is the element with `.correct-answer`? Did you miss adding that to fiddle in question?

Comment: Updated. Should have been `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the following script runs,

```
$(document).on("click", ".current", {
    qid: $(this).text()
}, GoToQuestion);
```

`$(this).text()` is executed immediately, "this" should be the `{qid: $(this).text()}` object. so value of `$(this).text()` is evaluated as "" to pass to the function GoToQuestion when you are click on it. Try to change it to the following code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".current", GoToQuestion);
function GoToQuestion(event) {
    $("#debug").append("<br />Passing data via function - event.data.qid: " + $(event.target).text());
}
```

Or use a anonymous function instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".current", function(event) {
    $("#debug").append("<br />Passing data via function - event.data.qid: " + $(event.target).text());
});
```

And simpler: use `$(this).text()` rather than `$(event.target).text()` in the function.

It should run as what you expected.

Comment: I just corrected the formatting mate. For multiple lines of code, select the entire block and do Ctrl + K :)

Comment: I think "this" in `{qid: $(this).text()}` is actually the window object, since it's not within any smaller scope. But the basic explanation is correct: "this" is not the element you want until you're inside the event handler function.